# Background color on a row in TGrid

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4, delphi-xe5

Have almost got Mike's solution with the manipulation of tgrid to work. The only thing I'd like to know is how to set the background in ApplyStyling procedure?

```
Procedure TFinanicalCell.ApplyStyling;
begin
  FontColor:= claBlue;
  Font.Size:= 18;
  // Background ?
    if Assigned(Font.OnChanged) then
      Font.OnChange(Font);
      Repaint;
end;
```

I also wonder why the value is 0 in my setData procedure?

```
Procedure TFinancialCell.SetData(const Value: TValue);
var
 F: Single;
begin

  F := Value.Astype<single>;
  inherited SetData(Format('%m',[F]));

end;
```

My GetValue procedure:

```
procedure TForm5.Grid1GetValue(Sender: TObject; const Col, Row: Integer; var Value: TValue);
 begin
   if Col = 0 then
    Value := Row
   else if Col = 1 then
   begin
    Value := FloatToStr(Data[Row]);
    if Data[Row] >30 then
    begin
     Value := '#' + FloatToStr(Data[Row]);
    end;
   end;
 end;
```

Comment: Check [`this question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16540477/960757). It was the second item from related list on the right side of this page.

Comment: @Arioch'The it is not a real dupe because of two questions in one (Styling and Data) and the Styling part is dupe :o)

Comment: What is your OnGetData code from the form?

Comment: Mike: My getValue method is implemented in my Form. I add the method to the code above so you can see it

Comment: I read the article "Changing TTextCell background color to runtime XE4" I do not quite understand what you mean by FindStyleResource('background') do I need to manually add the  rectangle from the Tool Palette? When I add FindStyleResource ('background') to ApplyStyle procedure I get nil?